# Pi Permanent Wiring

Tags: connectors

I want to finalize my Pi project and am concerned about the wire and connectors, gauge, durability, connection.  Do you think that I can use the standard pi jumper connectors as a permanent solution or is there a better "production" type connector?

https://www.modmypi.com/gpio-accessories/rpi-premium-jumper-wires-female-female

Comment: One of these https://www.adafruit.com/search?q=raspberry+pi+proto+board&b=1 paired with a ribbon cable may be a better choice long term.

Comment: I looked at that but it is too much piece.  I am more considering the single and double or triple type connections needed to connect peripherals.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give enough information about what you are connecting to answer.

I would use an IDC connector (possibly paired with coloured ribbon cable) for the Pi end.
These are used inside PCs to connect peripherals, so should be reliable.

I would solder the other ends to the circuitry at the other end, but this depends on what you are using.

I use a number of 2,3,4 & 6 pin connectors to make patch cords. These can often be scrounged from old computers.

Answer (score 0):

The *gauge* is obviously fine for anything running off the pi at a distance of 8".  The *durability* is also fine, considering the pi itself is kinda delicate and you haven't said anything special about the circumstances.  The casing is reasonably thick and doesn't split or crack unless cut.  You can tear them apart without accidentally exposing any metal.

Those are stranded aluminum and pretty easy to strip with an exacto knife if you want to solder them on at one end.  The only thing about them vs. a cable is it gets tedious pushing them individually onto the pi pins if you are going to plug and unplug whatever regularly.  However, the square connectors are the right dimensions to tape/glue together if you are connecting to a bunch of adjacent pins.

Answer (score 0):

For a permanent solution soldering is the most reliable method (I'm assuming wire-wrap isn't an option).

Dupont connectors may work loose with vibration.

Perhaps a 26 pin IDC socket at the Pi end with the other ends soldered to the components.